# modifying of 後ろ

Tags: grammar

I've got troubles with modifying 後ろを付いていく in the following sentence. Can somebody please explain this part for me. As far as I understand the sentence "Kicking around piled up snow, I'm following him."

[image]

As always thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

後ろ, 背中, and 後ろ姿 are often used in Japanese as if they had their own volition, particularly in modifying clauses.

You can say that a person's 背中 is walking off into the distance (歩いていく背中) -- this really means **that person** is walking into the distance, and the perspective of the scene is (the speaker) watching their back as they go.

So in this case, the speaker is following their 後ろ (i.e. behind them) as it (as they) `積もった雪を蹴散らすように進む`, `advance in a manner of kicking the piled-up snow about`.

Answer (score 2):

"I'm following him who is kicking around piled up snow."

It is he that is kicking around piled up snow